# Substitute last denominator of fractional expression recursively in Ruby

Tags: ruby, recursion

I want to make a function that step by step expands the infinite continued fraction of the square root of two, i.e.:

> ```
> sqrt 2 = 1 + 1/(2 + 1/(2 + 1/(2 + ... ))) = 1.414213...
> ```

Or more clearly:

[image: WikiPedia]

(From the [Wikipedia entry which illustrates the solution to quadratic equation x^2 = 2 (or x = sqrt 2) using continued fractions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solving_quadratic_equations_with_continued_fractions#A_simple_example))

The first four iterations are equal to:

> ```
> 1 + 1/2 = 3/2 = 1.5
> 1 + 1/(2 + 1/2) = 7/5 = 1.4
> 1 + 1/(2 + 1/(2 + 1/2)) = 17/12 = 1.41666...
> 1 + 1/(2 + 1/(2 + 1/(2 + 1/2))) = 41/29 = 1.41379...
> ```

In Ruby code we get:

```
1 + Rational(1, 2)
1 + Rational(1, 2 + Rational(1, 2))
1 + Rational(1, 2 + Rational(1, 2 + Rational(1, 2)))
1 + Rational(1, 2 + Rational(1, 2 + Rational(1, 2 + Rational(1, 2))))
```

As can be seen the last the last denominator (`2`) is replaced with `2 + Rational(1, 2)`  in every next iteration.

How do I write a function `expand` that can call itself and prints the results recursively?

Pseudo code:

```
def expand rational
  puts expand rational.replace_last_denominator_with(2 + Rational(1, 2))
end
```

The problem I am having is that I have no clean way to substitute this last part. I thought of converting the expression to a string, substituting the last number with the expression, and convert it back to code. But I am sure there must be a better way to approach this. I hope someone would be willing to help me.

Comment: It is not clear where the first step `1 + 1/2` comes from.

Comment: What do you mean by "replace the last element with `Rational(1, 2)`? If you replace the last element in `1 + Rational(1, 2)`, you get `1 + Rational(1, Rational(1, 2))`. Or if you mean "last element" as a "term", then, you get `1 + Rational(1, 2)`, which is the same as before replacing.

Comment: By the way, how does that fit your description that says "step by step expands"?

Comment: @sawa http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction#Fundamental_recurrence_formulas

Comment: Actually, it is not obvious what you have at the end of `...`, which is the place where the first step of calculation is to take place. It is not clear at all how you are trying to calculate.

Comment: @sawa I added a Wikipedia link which explains continued fractions. I am trying to solve Project [Euler question 57](http://projecteuler.net/problem=57), but the side effects of checking if the denominator is bigger than enumerator and keeping track of the first 1000 iterations to see how many are bigger are not necessary for me. To keep this question 'simple' I only want to print the value recursively. The `...` is `1/(2 + ...)` till infinity :-). Take a look at the Ruby example, the 2 (last denominator of the expression), is replaced with `2 + Rational(1, 2)`. PS Added the `2 +` I forgot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with string substitution and eval for first four iterations:

```
def expand rational_fraction, iteration
  new_rational_fraction = rational_fraction[0..-iteration].gsub(/2$/, '2 + Rational(1, 2' + ')' * iteration)
  iteration += 1
  puts eval(new_rational_fraction)
  expand new_rational_fraction, iteration if iteration <= 4
end

expand "1 + Rational(1,2)", 1

# => 3/2
#    7/5
#    17/12
#    41/29
```

If someone sees a way to not use string manipulation and `eval` while still implementing a recursive function I would be happy to hear.

/Edit

Got it! (By reading other people's answers on Project Euler 57 thread):

```
# Recursive function is last = 1+1/(1+last)
def expand rational_fraction, iteration
  puts rational_fraction
  new_rational_fraction = 1+1/(1+rational_fraction) 
  iteration += 1
  expand new_rational_fraction, iteration if iteration <= 4
end

expand 1 + Rational(1,2), 1

# => 3/2
#    7/5
#    17/12
#    41/29
```